# What is Mach-O type should I use it in my iOS Objective-C project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

What is Mach-O type in Build Setting in Xcode? and what should it be Set on?

it has these options "Executable" "Dynamic Library" "Bundle" "Static Library" "Relocatable Object File"

I had an error "Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group" since I changed it from Executable to Static Library my error went off, I wanna know is that ok that I changed it? and what all those options mean so I won't face another error in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

For more detail [Building Mach-O Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/1-Articles/building_files.html)
 and [Xcode Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html)

Answer (score 2):

**Mach-O Type(MACH_O_TYPE)**

[[Framework static vs dynamic]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57741985/4770877)

[[Mach-O format]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214522/4770877)

[Official page](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW73) which has some reflection in [loader.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.6.76/EXTERNAL_HEADERS/mach-o/loader.h). Additionally `MH_PRELOAD` 0x5, `MH_CORE` 0x4, `MH_DYLINKER` 0x7

To setup `Mach-O Type` determines a **linker** behaviour

```
Framework target -> Build Settings -> Mach-O Type
```

- `Executable` 0x2 (`mh_execute`/`mh_executable`) - Is not linked. Is used to create a launchable program - `Application`, `App extension - Widget`. `Application target` is a default setting
- `Bundle` 0x8 (`mh_bundle` .bundle) - `loadable bundle` - run time linked. iOS now supports only `Testing Bundle target` where it is a default setting to generate a `Loadable bundle`.
   `System` -> `Testing Bundle` -> `tested binary`. A location of `Testing Bundle` will be depended on target, static or dynamic binary...
- `Dynamic Library` 0x6 (`mh_dylib` .dylib or none) - Load/run time linked.

  - With `Framework target` - `Dynamic Library` is a default setting to generate a `Dynamic framework`
- `Static Library`(`staticlib` .a) - Compilation time(build time) linked.

  - With `Static Library target` - `Static Library` is a default setting to generate a `Static library`
  - With `Framework target` - `Static Library` to generate a `Static framework`
- `Relocatable Object File` 0x1 (`mh_object` .o) - Compilation time(build time) linked. It is the simplest form. It is a basement to create executable, static or dynamic format. Relocatable because variables and functions don't have any specific address

It is useful to use [`otool`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/otool/) to determine if binary is dynamic or not `-h` or `-hv`

```
-h     Display the Mach header.
-v     Display verbosely (symbolically) when possible.
```

```
otool -h <path_binary>
//e.g.
otool -h "/Users/alex/Desktop/projects_experiments/ios/LibraryAndFramework/BuildCustom/UtilsSwift/UtilsSwiftFramework.framework/UtilsSwiftFramework"

Mach header
      magic  cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
 0xfeedfacf 16777228          0  0x00           6    30       3488 0x00100085
```

`filetype` is a key point - 6 - 0x6 - Dynamic Library

[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)