# How to add files to an already created bridging header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I currently have a bridging header set up and I want to add more files to it but when I do so I get a "file not found" error:

[image: Error]

I know the pod is set up correctly.  I'm  pretty sure my bridging header is set up correctly. I have it in the  MyProject_Showcase-Bridging-Header.h format.  It's been added to Targets - Swift Compiler Code Generation. It looks like the first item on the bridging header is working fine. I'm not sure why it can't find the 2nd one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your syntax is incorrect. Try replicating the top import.

Something like `<fileDirectory/IQDropDownTextfield.h>`

Comment: I tried that, it causes more errors than just the file not found error

Comment: Is the framework saved correctly in your project directory? If it can't find it, it's likely that it's pointing to the wrong location.

Comment: It's from a pod. Would that affect it?

Comment: The framework should be in the top level of your directory, the same place your .xcodeproj file is. If it is saved another level down inside a directory name "Pods" or something of the like, you will need to include that with your import statement. Something like #import "Pods/IQDropDownTextField.h"

Comment: It's still giving the same error, I installed the pods using 'use_frameworks!' do you think that might have affected it

Comment: Are you using a static or dynamic framework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899799/ios-static-vs-dynamic-frameworks-clarifications

Comment: I got it to work, your first answer was right, all the errors being thrown were because were related to how I had the project set up before using the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Just type in the heather:

```
#import "file-to-import.h"
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, it says file not found

Comment: Try to "Clean" and then "Build" sometimes this helps me to get it working