# Adding custom cordova plugin to linked and embed framework in IOS XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I currently have this code in my custom cordova plugin,

```
<framework src="src/ios/Frameworks/XXX.framework" custom="true" embed="true"/>
<framework src="src/ios/Frameworks/XXXFramework.framework" custom="true" embed="true"/>
```

When I cordova build ios it will only go into embedded binaries but not linked frameworks and libraries. I wish to import both of the framework to both linked and embedded sections.

Please refer to Image below :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K334Z.gif)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I've found the solution:
[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650522/custom-cordova-plugin-add-framework-to-embedded-binaries/36723619)

Comment: Can you please share how you implemented this? I used the hook in the link of the solution you mentioned, but it breaks the integrity of the xworkspace.project.

Comment: @Logus Hi, you can try Joanne's solution below. Or try this [link](https://github.com/gouen95/Plugman-ionic2-plugin-config#extra-2--add-framework-to-linked-and-embedded). The link is for my own and colleagues' reference, sorry if it's hard to understand.

Comment: I solved it by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/xcode to add the framework with a simple method.

Answer (score 6):

For adding libraries to "Embedded Binaries" section in Xcode (Starting from cordova-ios 4.4.0 and cordova 7.0.0), put this in your plugin.xml:

```
<framework src="src/ios/XXX.framework"   embed="true" custom="true" />
```

For adding libraries to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section in Xcode,
put this in your plugin.xml:

```
<source-file src="src/ios/XXX.framework" target-dir="lib" framework="true" />
```

Both of them can exist at the same time. For example:

```
<platform name="ios">
    ....
    <source-file src="src/ios/XXX.m"/>
    <source-file src="src/ios/XXX.framework" target-dir="lib" framework="true" />
    <framework src="src/ios/XXX.framework"   embed="true" custom="true" /> 
    ....  
</platform>
```

Comment: Does a plugin need to do both, to have it added to both "Embedded Binaries" and "Linked Frameworks and Libraries?"

Comment: @trebor No. It depends on your implementation. You may refer to this thread as there's a very clear definition on it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33210611/1527788

Comment: This is woks fine for me. Thanks

Comment: Does not work any more