# What is the proper way of distributing a dynamic framework with a dependency on a static framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm building a closed source dynamic framework. It has a dependency on a 3rd party closed source static framework.

I link the static dependency framework to my framework's project/target as described in [this Apple tech note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html):

[image]

That same Apple tech note mentions:

> The app target is responsible for embedding all of the frameworks,
>   including any frameworks that other frameworks depend on.

So I also give my clients a copy of the framework I depend on. However, further down in the same tech note, Apple (referring to embedding static libraries/frameworks) states:

> Since the binary in these situations is a static library, apps cannot
>   embed it in the app bundle.
>
> ...The library should remain in the "Link Binary with Libraries"
>   section.

That's fine - so I just have my clients link the static framework dependency instead of embed it and everything works fine.

However, problems arise when my client needs the `-ObjC` linker flag for other libraries they use. This linker flag causes my (objective-c) static framework dependency to load all of its classes twice and the client sees duplicate class logs everywhere in their console.

One possible solution here would be to have the client identify the libraries they use which need the `-ObjC` linker flag and instead specify the `force_load` flag for those libraries. But this solution also causes problems in the case of the client using CocoaPods since CocoaPods will overwrite any changes to their linker flags with `-ObjC` again with each `pod install`. **Are there any other solutions/ideas anyone has to this problem?**

**P.S.** I know the Apple tech note from before also mentions:

> Static frameworks are not a supported way of sharing static libraries.

but unfortunately my hands are tied from business constraints at the moment, and I must include this static framework dependency.

Comment: Consider making your framework static instead of dynamic.

Comment: Hi Adam, in the absence of umbrella frameworks on iOS, I think Paul's suggestion is correct.  If you create a static framework then linking will be deferred to the time your client links, and this should resolve the duplicate symbol errors.

Comment: @par so to confirm - my dependency is being linked to my dynamic framework and then it is also being linked to the client's app when the `-ObjC` flag is present.

Comment: It seems that way, but I'm only speculating. I haven't had to deal with your specific problem and I don't have time unfortunately to make sample frameworks to dig into this deeper so my confidence in any solution I can provide is really low.

Comment: Strangely, everything seems to work fine if the client app adds my dependency static framework to their project by dragging it over to the project explorer, but then removes it from the 'linked libraries' section in the general tab.

Comment: Coming in 6 years late, did you get answer to Why we need to add 3rd party dependencies to client apps explicitly? If those dependencies are static, shouldn't they be automatically linked to your framework's binary and you don't have to ship them explicitly?